# How to repeatedly execute a method until said otherwise

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an EventSystem for managing my turn-based game in Unity.

```
public class EventSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static List<Action> _commandsQueue = new List<Action>();

    private bool _canExecuteCommand = true;

    public void AddToQueue(Action command)
    {
        _commandsQueue.Add(command);
    }

    private void StartCommandExecution()
    {
        _commandsQueue[0]();
        _canExecuteCommand = false;
    }

    public void CommandExecutionComplete()
    {
        _canExecuteCommand = true;
    }

    public void PlayFirstCommandFromQueue()
    {
        if (_commandsQueue.Any() && _canExecuteCommand)
        {
            StartCommandExecution();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("No Command In Queue");
        }
    }
}
```

How do I put a method in Update() until _canExecuteCommand is true again but only for some methods?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: As your question currently sits- it is very broad. "How to execute until I say otherwise?" Toss it in a loop, `for`, `while` `do...while`, etc. We can provide better answers for you with more information on what you're currently trying to achieve and why!

Answer (score 1):

It is quite broad what you are trying to do but in general you would use an endless loop within a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html).

You can create a generic routine which invokes any `Action` you pass in as parameter once a frame like e.g.

```
private IEnumerator InvokeEveryFrame(Action action)
{
    // This looks strange but is okey in a Coroutine as long as you yield somewhere within
    while(true)
    {
        action?.Invoke();

        // This tells Unity to "pause" this routine here
        // render the current frame and continue from here in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

So all that's left is starting the routine using [`MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) like e.g.

```
Coroutine routine = StartCoroutine(SomeParameterlessMethod);
```

or if you need parameters

```
Coroutine routine = StartCoroutine(() => SomeMethod(x, y, z));
```

and then at some point later stop it using [`MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html) and the stored [`Coroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html) reference like e.g.

```
StopCoroutine(routine);
```

how exactly you store that reference is up to you of course up to you.